# preg_match_all alphabetical list string e.g. A. {text). B. {text} etc

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to find a way to extract items from a string by matching against firstly "A.", "B.", "C." etc, getting each value before the next e.g. getting "A." right up until the next B. and then from B. up to the next C. if each exists.

**Example String 1:**

```
A. What sort of country do the framers of the Northwest Ordinance envision for the next generation of Americans?
B. How do the statements on behalf of individual religious rights and the public support of religion compare with the statements found in the new state constitutions?
```

In the above simple string I finally managed to use `preg_match_all('/(.*?)\?/', $aString, $matches);`. This was only after trying to understand each part of the regex and checking all other stackoverflow questions that were as close to mine as possible. This preg_match_all code seems to work other than the leading space on the second item:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'A. What sort of country do the framers of the Northwest Ordinance envision for the next generation of Americans?' (length=112)
      1 => string ' B. How do the statements on behalf of individual religious rights and the public support of religion compare with the statements found in the new state constitutions?' (length=167)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'A. What sort of country do the framers of the Northwest Ordinance envision for the next generation of Americans' (length=111)
      1 => string ' B. How do the statements on behalf of individual religious rights and the public support of religion compare with the statements found in the new state constitutions' (length=166)
```

**Example String 2:**

```
A. What explains President Lincoln’s attitude toward Louisiana in his letter to General Banks? Does his Second Inaugural Address explain his attitude? How do Lincoln, Douglass, and Stevens’ attitudes toward the South differ? Is Stevens’ constitutional argument about the basis of Reconstruction sound? If so, was that sufficient to make his approach to the seceded states sound? Do Stevens’ remarks about Jews, the Irish and others undermine his claim to be a champion of the principles of the Declaration of Independence? Was the response of Southerners as described and defended by Tillman inevitable, or could some version of restoration or reconstruction have prevented it?
B. Do the views expressed in the twentieth century differ from those expressed in the documents below? For example, compare the views of Senators Tillman and Thurmond, both Democrats from South Carolina. Did the constitutional arguments change between the 1860s and the 1960s?
C. How true does President Abraham Lincoln’s remark in his Second Inaugural Address that both Northerners and Southerners prayed to the same God and read the same Bible appear in light of the very different interpretations of said Bible on the question of slavery, as evidenced in the antebellum period?
```

The problem comes in that in this second example, I can't just try get each string ending in "?", because "A." contains multiple items with a "?" that should be part of the first extraction up until the next "B." then "C." and so on. The result I am trying to get is this:

```
array (size=3)
   0 => string 'A. What explains President Lincoln’s attitude toward Louisiana in his letter to General Banks? Does his Second Inaugural Address explain his attitude? How do Lincoln, Douglass, and Stevens’ attitudes toward the South differ? Is Stevens’ constitutional argument about the basis of Reconstruction sound? If so, was that sufficient to make his approach to the seceded states sound? Do Stevens’ remarks about Jews, the Irish and others undermine his claim to be a champion of the principles of the Declaration of Independence? Was the response of Southerners as described and defended by Tillman inevitable, or could some version of restoration or reconstruction have prevented it?'
   1 => string 'B. Do the views expressed in the twentieth century differ from those expressed in the documents below? For example, compare the views of Senators Tillman and Thurmond, both Democrats from South Carolina. Did the constitutional arguments change between the 1860s and the 1960s?'
   2 => string 'C. How true does President Abraham Lincoln’s remark in his Second Inaugural Address that both Northerners and Southerners prayed to the same God and read the same Bible appear in light of the very different interpretations of said Bible on the question of slavery, as evidenced in the antebellum period?'
```

The total size of the array of string I am looping through to run this on is 813. Each one varies between example 1 and 2. The one thing they share in common is each question starts with an "A.", then if another question is in the string it will be a "B." and so on. My other concern is if this is possible without the server throwing resource limit errors or something.

Comment: Please, don't post solution in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
(?sm)\b[A-Z]\..*?\?(?=\h+[A-Z]\.|$)
```

- `(?sm)` Inline modifier, dot matches a newline and enable multiline
- `\b[A-Z]\.` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, match an uppercase char A-Z and `.`
- `.*?\?` Match as least as possible chars until the first `?`
- `(?=\h+[A-Z]\.|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is  either 1+ horizontal whitspace chars followed by an uppercase char and `.` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJqNUR/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/fNgdP)

For example

```
$re = '/\b[A-Z]\..*?\?(?=\h+[A-Z]\.|$)/sm';
$str = 'A. What explains President Lincoln’s attitude toward Louisiana in his letter to General Banks? Does his Second Inaugural Address explain his attitude? How do Lincoln, Douglass, and Stevens’ attitudes toward the South differ? Is Stevens’ constitutional argument about the basis of Reconstruction sound? If so, was that sufficient to make his approach to the seceded states sound? Do Stevens’ remarks about Jews, the Irish and others undermine his claim to be a champion of the principles of the Declaration of Independence? Was the response of Southerners as described and defended by Tillman inevitable, or could some version of restoration or reconstruction have prevented it?
B. Do the views expressed in the twentieth century differ from those expressed in the documents below? For example, compare the views of Senators Tillman and Thurmond, both Democrats from South Carolina. Did the constitutional arguments change between the 1860s and the 1960s?
C. How true does President Abraham Lincoln’s remark in his Second Inaugural Address that both Northerners and Southerners prayed to the same God and read the same Bible appear in light of the very different interpretations of said Bible on the question of slavery, as evidenced in the antebellum period?';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => A. What explains President Lincoln’s attitude toward Louisiana in his letter to General Banks? Does his Second Inaugural Address explain his attitude? How do Lincoln, Douglass, and Stevens’ attitudes toward the South differ? Is Stevens’ constitutional argument about the basis of Reconstruction sound? If so, was that sufficient to make his approach to the seceded states sound? Do Stevens’ remarks about Jews, the Irish and others undermine his claim to be a champion of the principles of the Declaration of Independence? Was the response of Southerners as described and defended by Tillman inevitable, or could some version of restoration or reconstruction have prevented it?
    [1] => B. Do the views expressed in the twentieth century differ from those expressed in the documents below? For example, compare the views of Senators Tillman and Thurmond, both Democrats from South Carolina. Did the constitutional arguments change between the 1860s and the 1960s?
    [2] => C. How true does President Abraham Lincoln’s remark in his Second Inaugural Address that both Northerners and Southerners prayed to the same God and read the same Bible appear in light of the very different interpretations of said Bible on the question of slavery, as evidenced in the antebellum period?
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works really well. One small hiccup though, if the string contains an invisible linebreak between each then it does not work. Only C. ends up being returned. But I can solve this by using: `$aString = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $aString);` on the string. I just want to double-check if I am doing that str_replace unnecessarily?

Comment: @KyleKnight The `(?s)` modifier will enable the dot to match a newline as well, so you don't have to replace the newlines.

Comment: for some reason it does not work though. I copy-pasted the exact string in my question and only "C." is returned?

Comment: @KyleKnight I have added a demo, you could use `(?sm)\b[A-Z]\..*?\?(?=\h+[A-Z]\.|$)` or add the flags after the pattern `/\b[A-Z]\..*?\?(?=\h+[A-Z]\.|$)/sm`